# Sans serif title in amsart

Tags: titles, amsart, sans-serif

I want to write a title of an `amsart` document using (bold) sans-serif, and I tried
`\title{\textsf{My Title}}` and  the result is good *modulo* the fact that the header is in sans serif and I want a header in a normal font (roman).
How can the problem be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change what `\@settitle` does.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\makeatletter
\def\@settitle{%
  \begin{center}%
  \baselineskip14\p@\relax
  %  \bfseries % <-- original
  \sffamily    % <-- change
  \uppercasenonmath\@title
  \@title
  \end{center}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{The title of this paper}
\author{Me}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[40][1-2]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]